# bootstrap модальное окно внутри slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap, slick.js

Использую bootstrap 3.

Есть такой код [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/favolif/edit?html,css,js,output):

```js
$('.slider-product').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  
  $this.slick({
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,               
    dots: false,
    infinite: true, 
  }); 
});


$(window).load(function(){
    $('.slider-product').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.on('setPosition', function () {
            $(this).find('.slick-slide').height('auto');
            var slickTrack = $(this).find('.slick-track');
            var slickTrackHeight = $(slickTrack).height();
            $(this).find('.slick-slide').css('height', slickTrackHeight + 'px');
        });
    });   
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');



.tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: block !important;   
    height: 0 !important;         
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.tab-content > .active {
    height: auto !important;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>


  <ul class="slider-filter nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#popular-1" data-toggle="tab">
        1 вкладка
      </a>
    </li>      
    <li>
      <a href="#popular-2" data-toggle="tab">
        2 вкладка
      </a>
    </li>   
  </ul>
  
  
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="popular-1" class="tab-pane fade in active">  
    <div class="slider-product">

      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-buy-click" data-target="#modalClick" data-toggle="modal">
          1/ открыть модальное окно
        </a>

        <div class="order-modal modal fade" id="modalClick" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>    
              <div class="modal-body">
                1/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus incidunt molestias quo nihil illum perspiciatis tempore! Sed necessitatibus a, eligendi.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-buy-click" data-target="#modalClick" data-toggle="modal">
          2/ открыть модальное окно
        </a>

        <div class="order-modal modal fade" id="modalClick" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>    
              <div class="modal-body">
                2/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus incidunt molestias quo nihil illum perspiciatis tempore! Sed necessitatibus a, eligendi.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-buy-click" data-target="#modalClick" data-toggle="modal">
          3/ открыть модальное окно
        </a>

        <div class="order-modal modal fade" id="modalClick" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>    
              <div class="modal-body">
                3/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus incidunt molestias quo nihil illum perspiciatis tempore! Sed necessitatibus a, eligendi.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="popular-2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="slider-product">

      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-buy-click" data-target="#modalClick" data-toggle="modal">
          1/ открыть модальное окно
        </a>

        <div class="order-modal modal fade" id="modalClick" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>    
              <div class="modal-body">
                1/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus incidunt molestias quo nihil illum perspiciatis tempore! Sed necessitatibus a, eligendi.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-buy-click" data-target="#modalClick" data-toggle="modal">
          2/ открыть модальное окно
        </a>

        <div class="order-modal modal fade" id="modalClick" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>    
              <div class="modal-body">
                2/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus incidunt molestias quo nihil illum perspiciatis tempore! Sed necessitatibus a, eligendi.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-buy-click" data-target="#modalClick" data-toggle="modal">
          3/ открыть модальное окно
        </a>

        <div class="order-modal modal fade" id="modalClick" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>    
              <div class="modal-body">
                3/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus incidunt molestias quo nihil illum perspiciatis tempore! Sed necessitatibus a, eligendi.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Есть Бутстраповские табы (вкладки), внутри которых расположен slick слайдер.

В каждом пункте слайдера `.slick-slide` есть кнпка\ссылка вызова стандартного бутстраповского модального окна + тут же расположены эти модальные окна (именно так и никак иначе, только внтри `.slick-slide`).

**Проблема** в том, что окно (хотя и `position: fixed`) позиционируется неправильно и маска окна перекрывает само окно, закрытие не работает).

**Вопрос:** Как, при клике на кнопку\ссылку, открыть bootstrap модальное окно, так чтобы оно правильно позиционировалось и работало без изъянов, если и кнопка\ссылка и само модальное окно располагается внутри пункта slick слайдера (внутри каждого `.slick-slide`)?

Comment: У меня такая же проблема нарисовалась!Как вы ее решили эту проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Тут проблема в том, что модалка с `position:fixed` находится внутри элемента с `transform`. В данном случае `.slick-track`. Наглядный пример со вроде бы независимым фиксированным окном с выравниванием по центру:

```css
.modal{
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  background: #cda;
}
.wrapper{
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
```

Можно вывести разметку модальных окон за пределы слайдера при помощи js:

```js
//перенос модальных окон в конец документа при инициализации слайдера
$('.slider-product').on('init', function(e, slick) {
  slick.$slides.find('.modal').appendTo('body');

  //из слайдов-клонов модалки долой. Для порядка
  $(this).find('.slick-cloned .modal').remove();
})

$('.slider-product').slick({
  slidesToShow: 2
});

//обновление слайдеров после открытии таба
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', function() {
  $('.slick-slider').filter(':visible').slick('setPosition');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>


<ul class="slider-filter nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#popular-1" data-toggle="tab">
        1 вкладка
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#popular-2" data-toggle="tab">
        2 вкладка
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="popular-1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="slider-product">

      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-buy-click" data-target="#modalClick" data-toggle="modal">
          1/ открыть модальное окно
        </a>

        <div class="order-modal modal fade" id="modalClick" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="modal-body">
                1/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus incidunt molestias quo nihil illum perspiciatis tempore! Sed necessitatibus a, eligendi.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-buy-click" data-target="#modalClick1" data-toggle="modal">
          2/ открыть модальное окно
        </a>

        <div class="order-modal modal fade" id="modalClick1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="modal-body">
                2/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus incidunt molestias quo nihil illum perspiciatis tempore! Sed necessitatibus a, eligendi.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-buy-click" data-target="#modalClick2" data-toggle="modal">
          3/ открыть модальное окно
        </a>

        <div class="order-modal modal fade" id="modalClick2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="modal-body">
                3/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus incidunt molestias quo nihil illum perspiciatis tempore! Sed necessitatibus a, eligendi.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="popular-2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="slider-product">

      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-buy-click" data-target="#modalClick3" data-toggle="modal">
          1/ открыть модальное окно
        </a>

        <div class="order-modal modal fade" id="modalClick3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="modal-body">
                1/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus incidunt molestias quo nihil illum perspiciatis tempore! Sed necessitatibus a, eligendi.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-buy-click" data-target="#modalClick4" data-toggle="modal">
          2/ открыть модальное окно
        </a>

        <div class="order-modal modal fade" id="modalClick4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="modal-body">
                2/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus incidunt molestias quo nihil illum perspiciatis tempore! Sed necessitatibus a, eligendi.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-buy-click" data-target="#modalClick5" data-toggle="modal">
          3/ открыть модальное окно
        </a>

        <div class="order-modal modal fade" id="modalClick5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="modal-body">
                3/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus incidunt molestias quo nihil illum perspiciatis tempore! Sed necessitatibus a, eligendi.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: проблема в том, что модалка изначально с ```display: none``` в таких блоках (не только модалках) слик слайдер сложно активировать. Но спсасибо за попытку помочь!

Comment: @HamSter , тут я таки могу с вами поспорить. Уберите все свойства `transform` (в т.ч. с префиксами) для `.slick-track` и модалка появляется как ни в чём не бывало поверх затемнения

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблема с z-index-ами у модального окна он равен 1050, а у подложки 1040. но проблема в том что slick имеет posiion relative и не дает потомкам вылезти выше чем его слой, меняйте z-index slick слайдеру. Еще проблема в том что для перемещения slick слайдер transform и создает локальную систему координат, т.е. ваш fixed теперь отображается относительно slick-track. Вам скорее всего придется выносить модалку из слайдера

Comment: а Вы пробовали менять его прежде чем писать ответ?)

Comment: если не пробовали, то я уже все перепробовала и z-index тут не при чем, но проблема да, однозначно, в слайдере. Все равно спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @HamSter пардон, я думал ваша проблема в перекрытии подложкой, поправил ответ